# How do I implement a pull down animation effect for my swipe down function?

Tags: android

I have a recycler view, on which I implemented a swipe down from the top, which opens another page.

I want to implement a pull-down animation effect with the same functionality, that, if you pull the RecyclerView down from the top, then a new page (activity switch) opens.

This is my `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.surajpatil.sp_gesture;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList<String> roomNames = new ArrayList<>();
    roomNames.add("Hall");
    roomNames.add("Dinning");
    roomNames.add("Patio");
    roomNames.add("Bedroom");
    roomNames.add("Master Bedroom");
    roomNames.add("Kitchen");
    roomNames.add("Porch");
    roomNames.add("Hall Way");
    roomNames.add("Bathroom");

    GestureRecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvRooms);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, roomNames);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setOnRecyclerViewGestureListener(new GestureRecyclerView.OnRecyclerViewGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollUp() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Scroll Up ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Swipe Left ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onSipeRight() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Swipe Right ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollDown() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Scroll Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeDownOverFirstItem() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Swipe Bottom", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent roomIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RoomActivity.class);
            startActivity(roomIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is my `GestureRecyclerView.java`

```
package com.example.surajpatil.sp_gesture;


public class GestureRecyclerView extends RecyclerView implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private OnRecyclerViewGestureListener onRecyclerViewGestureListener;

public GestureRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public GestureRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public GestureRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}


public void setOnRecyclerViewGestureListener(OnRecyclerViewGestureListener onRecyclerViewGestureListener) {
    this.onRecyclerViewGestureListener = onRecyclerViewGestureListener;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    return super.onTouchEvent(e);
}

private void init(){
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(),this);
}



//Calculate the swipe gestures
//You can customize the swipe threshold values as per your need, they just represent the velocity threshold of the swipe

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 300;
    final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 150;
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffX > 0) {
                    onRecyclerViewGestureListener.onSipeRight();
                } else {
                    onRecyclerViewGestureListener.onSwipeLeft();

                }
                result = true;
            }
        }
        else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (diffY > 0) {
                if (((LinearLayoutManager)getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                    onRecyclerViewGestureListener.onSwipeDownOverFirstItem();
                }else {
                    onRecyclerViewGestureListener.onScrollDown();
                }
            } else {
                onRecyclerViewGestureListener.onScrollUp();
            }
            result = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}


//Callbacks to listen to the different swipe events.
interface OnRecyclerViewGestureListener{
    void onScrollUp();
    void onSwipeLeft();
    void onSipeRight();
    void onScrollDown();
    void onSwipeDownOverFirstItem(); // Gets called when the swipe down gesture is detected and the list has reached to the top position.
}


//Intercepting the touch event from the user touch and passing it on to the Gesture Detector
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
}


@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}
}
```

Apart from this, I have a MyRecyclerView.java, RoomActivity.java, main_activity.xml, recyclerview_row.xml, and room.xml in my project.

This code detects the swipe gestures properly, now I want to implement the pull-down animation along with swipe down from top function.

Answer (score -1):

Add `SwipeRefreshLayout` layout in your root activity which contains recycler view.
Sample :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RecyclerView
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Further use the interface callback `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener` to perform action.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This creates another layer of view on top of the RecyclerView and shows a refresh icon while pulling down.
I don't want that; I want to pull the RecyclerView down! 
Currently, it is stationary in one position; I want to pull it down while swiping down from the top.